# Truncate a table in SQL workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables: Person and Customer, with the same PK ("customer" is a subtype of person: the pk of person (SSN) is the same PK of customer). These tables are connected by an identifying relationship.

When I try to truncate the father table "customer" I receive the following error message:

> 'Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint"

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_Customer_T_Person_T1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Person_T_SSN`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`Prson_T` (`SSN`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

As you can see I already added the constraint "on delete cascade": when a row in person is deleted, in the table customer will be deleted the row having the same SSN of the one deleted.

But when I try to truncate, it does not work. Why?

Comment: Does some third table related to the table to be truncated exists?

Comment: Yes, there is another table, MANAGER, which is another subtype of PERSON, connected with an identifying relationship  @Akina

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html):

> To achieve high performance, `TRUNCATE TABLE` bypasses the DML method
> of deleting data. Thus, (...) **it cannot be performed for InnoDB tables
> with parent-child foreign key relationships**, (...)

(Emphasis: me)

To make the `ON DELETE CASCADE` fire, use a normal DML `DELETE`.

Comment: So, to delete all the rows in "PERSON" I just do:  DELETE FROM db.Person_T; ? I can see the results is the same of TRUNCATE db.Person_T; (all the rows should be cancelled) . With delete it works, with truncate not. So, should I use DELETE? there is no problem?

Comment: @Jenny: Yes, `DELETE` without a `WHERE` clause just deletes all rows in a table. There is no "problem" per se but as described in the documentation `TRUNCATE` can be faster because all the DML processing is skipped. But of course, if you need that, you cannot skip it.

Comment: @Jenny Reproduce your issue with DELETE statement on some online fiddle (real and complete structures, 3-5 rows per table).